# %1 не является приложением Win32

Tags: python, pyinstaller

При конвертировании программы в .exe с помощью auto-py-to-exe возникло исключение:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\mind\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 35, in pywin32error
    yield
  File "c:\users\mind\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 43, in LoadLibraryEx
    return _dll._LoadLibraryEx(fileName, 0, flags)
  File "c:\users\mind\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi\_dll.py", line 26, in _LoadLibraryEx
    function_name='LoadLibraryEx')
  File "c:\users\mind\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi\_util.py", line 81, in __call__
    self._raise_error(function_name)
  File "c:\users\mind\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\core\cffi\_util.py", line 92, in _raise_error
    raise exception
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 не является приложением Win32

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\mind\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\win32\icon.py", line 231, in CopyIcons
    hsrc = win32api.LoadLibraryEx(srcpath, 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE)
  File "c:\users\mind\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\win32api.py", line 43, in LoadLibraryEx
    return _dll._LoadLibraryEx(fileName, 0, flags)
  File "c:\users\mind\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\contextlib.py", line 100, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "c:\users\mind\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\win32ctypes\pywin32\pywintypes.py", line 37, in pywin32error
    raise error(exception.winerror, exception.function, exception.strerror)
win32ctypes.pywin32.pywintypes.error: (193, 'LoadLibraryEx', '%1 не является приложением Win32')
```

Просто код работает. Подскажите как мне исправить эту ошибку, буду очень благордарен

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему изменив путь к файлу, убрав пробелы